# Subdomains located on a different IP address?

Tags: php, bash, .htaccess, server

I am developing an application in which i need to create sub-domains. There will be admin panel where i enter details for sub-domain and there relative ip addresses  and want to create a sub-domain located on different server
example:-

in admin panel i enter

my main website-- is xyz.com

folder name -- abc

folder server IP address: 192.168.0.52 (any ip)

then it should create : abc.xyz.com

and when opening  abc.xyz.com it should load files from that ip address

langugae used : PHP, Bash Scripting

Comment: Try as I might, I can't find a question anywhere in there.  There is a question mark, but that's not a substitute for an actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
RewriteRule ^(abc/.*)$ http://abc.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Should give you the URL `www.abc.xyc.com`

Comment: how will i mange the dns records ??